# Patch gets not applied to Drupal locally in DDEV built with Composer from the Drupal Git repo

Tags: composer, 9

I try to build a local workflow to be able to review patches for core. I am using DDEV for the local environment. Steps I have taken:

```
git clone https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git .
ddev config --mariadb-version=10.3
git checkout 9.1.x #I've chosen that way cuz with detached head I am unable to install composer packages
ddev composer install
ddev composer require --dev drush/drush
ddev . drush si standard --account-name=myuser --account-pass=mypassword --account-mail=my@mail.local --site-name="D9 Test"
ddev . drush en help_topics
ddev composer require --dev cweagans/composer-patches
```

Then I've added the following part to the `composer.json` `extra` section

```
"enable-patching":true,
"composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
"patches": {
   "drupal/core": {
       "#3044059-48: Convert big_pipe, dynamic_page_cache, page_cache module hook_help() to topic(s) (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3044059)": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-01-13/3044059-48.patch"
   }
},
```

When I perform a `ddev composer update -vvv` now the first odd thing is I get:

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Removing package drupal/core so that it can be re-installed and re-patched.
  - Removing drupal/core (9.1.x-dev), source is still present in core
Deleting core - not deleted
```

In the tutorials and documentation I've learned normally core gets deleted in that step? Next I get an exception with `drupal/coder`

```
  - Updating drupal/coder (8.3.8 => 8.3.9): Executing command (/var/www/html/vendor/drupal/coder): git show-ref --head -d
Executing command (/var/www/html/vendor/drupal/coder): git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no
    The package has modified files:
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/ArrayUnitTest.1.inc
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/ArrayUnitTest.inc
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/ArrayUnitTest.inc.fixed
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/ArrayUnitTest.php
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/DisallowLongArraySyntaxUnitTest.php
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/disallow_long_array_d7/DisallowLongArraySyntaxUnitTest.1.inc
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/disallow_long_array_d7/disallow_long_array_d7.info
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/disallow_long_array_d8/DisallowLongArraySyntaxUnitTest.2.inc
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/disallow_long_array_d8/DisallowLongArraySyntaxUnitTest.2.inc.fixed
    D coder_sniffer/Drupal/Test/Arrays/disallow_long_array_d8/disallow_long_array_d8.info.yml
    289 more files modified, choose "v" to view the full list
    Discard changes [y,n,v,d,s,?]? y
```

I've chosen `yes` and proceeded and get for the patch part the following output:

```
- Installing drupal/core (9.1.x-dev): Source already present
    REASON: Required by the root package: Install command rule (install drupal/core 9.1.x-dev|install drupal/core 9.1.x-dev)

  - Applying patches for drupal/core
    https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-01-13/3044059-48.patch (#3044059-48: Convert big_pipe, dynamic_page_cache, page_cache module hook_help() to topic(s) (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3044059))
Downloading https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-01-13/3044059-48.patch
patch '-p1' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d 'core' < '/tmp/5eb75f842ba88.patch'
Executing command (CWD): patch '-p1' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d 'core' < '/tmp/5eb75f842ba88.patch'
patching file core/modules/help_topics/help_topics/core.performance.html.twig
```

The output states that the file `core/modules/help_topics/help_topics/core.performance.html.twig` was patched. But problem is there isn't any `core.performance.html.twig` file. It doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Isn't this connected to https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8893?

Comment: to be honest i dont know, that exceeds my technical knowledge to judge that :/ i've quickly tried to lock the version of `coder` to the one from the initial git pull from drupal.org so it isn't the semantic version one mentioned in the issue. but the changes from above showed up never the less and the patches hasn't got applied still. :/

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I suggest that you change your workflow slightly - start to use the mglaman/drupalorg-cli project. Install it with Composer (like you do with Drush). The just run "vendor/bin/drupalorg issue:apply 3044059" to create an issue-branch and apply the latest patch for that issue. If you have any changes to the issue, commit them to the branch and run "drupalorg issue:patch" and "drupalorg issue:interdiff" to get files for uploading to the drupal.org issue queue.

Comment: well i would still be curious how to get things going with my initial issue with composer-patches ;) but your suggested tweaked workflow looks super interesting (and tempting)! only downside the install via composer is deprecated (and when trying requiring anyway the install failed due to a `symfony/console` version requirement mismatch). with ddev the composer variant would be desirable - like how things are dealt with `drush`. nevertheless tried the phar version also and it worked flawlessly out of the box. i will investigate and play around more with that. thanks!

Comment: permission issue maybe? doesn't have perm to create file?

Comment: Even if the readme says that "composer global require mglaman/drupalorg-cli" is deprecated it works just fine. I prefer using cgr - https://github.com/consolidation/cgr - when I do global installations.

Comment: @noSssweat hmmm the help_topics directory the `core.performance.html.twig` went into has drwxr-xr-x right after composer install

Comment: @hansfn hmmm yep globally but i hoped it would be possible to install locally like with drush. that way it failed and isn't recommend nor documented. and the `cgr`for global composer installs i haven't known yet. thanks!